# Should I represent two distinct relationships via only one associative table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a database to store the *news* of my website. The *news* entity type is associated with two different ones; *images* (which from the point of view of the app users are grouped in a *gallery*) and *categories*.

To represent this situation this, I have some tables like this:

```
image
id | src

category
id | name

news
id | title | text | author | ...
```

It is important to mention that each *news* may have multiple *images* and belong to multiple *categories*. So, to create the relationship between *images*, *categories* and *news*, I'll use another table, but my **question** is:

Should I have **(a)** two tables (one for *image* rows and other for *category* rows) or **(b)** just one with multiple columns? For example:

**(a)** Two distinct tables, one called `news_relationship_category`, with the column headings

```
id | id_news | id_category
```

and another one, named `news_relationship_gallery` set up as follows

```
 id | id_news | id_gallery
```

**(b)** One single table, entitled `news_relationships` with the headings

```
id_news | id_category | id_gallery
```

and INSERT INTO it rows with some columns that accept NULL marks, for instance:

```
10 | NULL | 3
---+------+------
10 | 27   | NULL
---+------+------
```

These are simple examples, but imagine if I have an *e-commerce* table, with *products* involved in multiple relationships. What is the best way to approach this case?

Comment: If your news can have 3 categories and 4 images, use the second approach. Is the one that best represents your situation. And don't use `id`. Use `id_news`, `id_gallery` and `id_category` all the time. It's far more clear. Your `new_relation_category` does *not* need an id for itself: it's just `(id_news, id_category)`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that each news may have multiple images and multiple categories. So you mean I should have one relational table for each area? One for gallery and one for category? @joanolo

Comment: That's it: one for gallery and one for category. (This, obviously, assumes that galleries and categories are, in principle, not directly related; meaning you don't have *one* gallery per category).

Comment: And you may want a category:gallery relationship?  Hence, a 3rd table?

Comment: Sketch out the `SELECTs` you will be doing -- _they_ may provide your answer !

Answer (score 0):

To delete a news-category pair in schema B, you have to do either a `DELETE` or an `UPDATE` depending on whether the relevant row has `id_gallery` specified or not. How about inserts, are you going to just `INSERT` or check first for rows with nulls to `UPDATE`?

So, I strongly recommend option A. However, I would drop the surrogate `id` columns and use `(id_news, id_category)` and `(id_news, id_gallery)` as PK.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it appears that you will need five tables to do this:

```
images ← newsimages ← news → newscategories → categories
```

Here the `news` table is linked to the categories via an associative table `newscategories` which is the only way to get a many-to-many relationship between `news` and `categories`.

[image]

The `newscategories` associative table simply contains a collection of *unique* associations between `news` and categories. You can get this by combining the two foreign keys as a single primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE newscategories (
    newsid INT REFERENCES news(id),
    categoryid INT REFERENCES categories(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(newsid,categoryid)
);
```

You would do exactly the same for the `images` table.

If you want to get a list of, say, categories, you can use a combination of `group_concat` and either a sub query or a common table expression if your MariaDB/MySQL is recent enough:

```
SELECT
    id,title,
    group_concat(category)
FROM (
    SELECT
        n.id,
        n.title,n.text,
        c.name as category
    FROM news AS n
    JOIN newscategories AS nc ON n.id=nc.newsid
    JOIN categories AS c on nc.categoriesid=c.id
) AS cte
GROUP BY id,title;
```

You can see an example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/219526/2 . However:

- The last example doesn’t work properly, but it does on a real server
- It would have been easier if you could use Common Table Expressions, but SQLFiddle doesn’t appear to support more recent versions.